# SSRS Subtotals in Filtered Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

[OUTPUT OF CURRENT REPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBBxj.jpg)

I have attached an image of my rdlc.[The arrows point to the row and column groups I will reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtqm6.png)

There is a field which outputs either a 1 or a 0 based on whether it is a "supplementary event" or not. For context, this is things like ice cream, programmes when you go see a show.

The row group is grouped on Order ID to show a row per order, and is filtered to ONLY show orders which contain events with BOTH a 1 and a 0. Meaning they have booked a main ticket and a supplementary item. This is working perfectly.

The first column group is filtered to show the main event they have booked for, so supplementary event = 0. When you run the data, you will only ever include one main event, so this column is fine.

The second column group with the red arrow is filtered to only show events where supplementary event = 1, and is grouped on event name which splits out each supplementary event giving the totals for each. The end result is a report which shows how many supplementary events a customer has booked for a main event.

[Excel of Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXR8R.png)

What I'm struggling with is getting totals for each supplementary event as shown in red above.

I can't just Sum(), because the rows have been filtered to only show customers who have purchased 2 different types of event, but the total has to sit outside of this group as it's grouped on order ID and I'm after the total.

If you need any more information please let me know.

I have tried Sum() but that includes orders which only have a supplementary item and not a main event which I don't want
I have tried Sum(field, "OrderIDgroup") but that errors as it's referencing the a row group outside of it.
I've played with Code.AddTotal() and Code.GetTotal() and they are pulling incorrect figures.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/uzoeqielm1srv68yi3j2b/ReportTemplate.rdlc?rlkey=2us0l1zncuvxp7psp19yubc41&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eaux5nqk9pb6a3ai4cir4/ReportData.xml?rlkey=11jszf6l8ix9xkldtojuzsuc6&dl=0

Comment: Without looking into this too much have you tried summing the report item? If not the get the name of the textbox where the expression is that you want to sum (in your case the second column group where you have the existing sum expression. Look at the name property (e.g. `Textbox123`) and then on your total row, use the expression `=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox123.Value)` (it's case sensitive).

Comment: Sadly in this version of ssrs summing report items isn't possible :( thanks so much for looking though!

Comment: What makes you say that? I'm pretty sure I used to use this years ago on SSRS2008. Are you getting an error message, if so what does it say? If this does not help, please edit your question and add some sample data so I can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Actually, it *might* be because the sum is not in the header/footer...(memory fading!). So, post some sample data and I'll take a look, if you can share a sample rdl too that would save time.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look @AlanSchofield - I will attach data and rdl now.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have linked via dropbox as couldn't attach - let me know that works okay.

Comment: I got both the files. I've converted to a standard RDL and recreated the data as a sql source as it's easier than XML but I'm not sure if the results are what you expect (before even look at the initial issue). Could you post a screen shot of the report running using the sample data you provided so I can compare them. That way at least I'll know that the base sample data I'm using is OK. Looking at it so far though, I think it's the group and row filters that are the problem but I might have a way around this - one step ata time though, send the screenshot when you can.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate you taking the time to look. I have uploaded an image of the current output with the link OUTPUT OF CURRENT REPORT in the original post. 
If you need me to send the data in another format let me know. I use XML and RDLC in visual studio but can get other formats.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield - Just wondered if you'd had any time to look into this? No problem if not, it may be that it's just not possible but I'm hoping for a festive miracle!

Comment: Sorry, I've been snowed under at work. I might try to have a look later tonight, let's just hope the answer isn't a Christmas turkey!

Comment: I spent a bit of time on this tonight until I remembered that you are working with XML data and not a SQL source. I tried to get it working in the report at first but the filters on the row and column groups simultaneously means it's either impossible to do or I've not got enough brain power to work it out... I then reverted to doing it in "the database" and got it working then the penny dropped. :( I can share the rdl if it might help but I know very little about SSRS with XML

Comment: Thank you so much for trying Alan! If you're able to share the rdl that would be great. I really, really appreciate everything.

Comment: No problem. Here's a link to the RDL. You'll need to open this in Report Builder or add it to an SSRS solution in Visual Studio. You also have to configure the datasource, it can point anywhere as the data is all generated in the dataset query. If you look at the end of the query, after the long INSERT statement, you'll see the key part that allows the report to work. https://1drv.ms/f/s!Al1Kq21dFT1ilcBE6Fy6ocl1B4kmSA?e=aAdGkf